# How to change the password of a wifi network when not in range?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm pretty sure I was able to do this with older versions of Windows.  I'm expecting to find a list of wireless networks that I've saved, and then I can change the password for any or all of them.

In Windows 10, the settings charm-thing that has the list of saved WiFi  networks does not let you see or change the WiFi password.

In classic control panel options, you can only view or change a WiFi network that is in range.

The network I want to change is not in range.

Doing a DDG search yields me basics of how to connect to a WiFi network, or change the password for a network that is in range.